# flex mobile project : memory management

Tags: apache-flex, memory-management

I have developed my first  flex mobile application which is of TabbedViewNavigatorApplication. Application is working fine but when I  test the application  in "profile handler", memory usage goes on increasing as I navigate through the application. When I came to know that,  I  have to remove all the added eventlisteners and I have to nullify the objects which are no longer needed. When I switch between tabs , tabs are initialising again and again.

I dont know where can I remove the eventlisteners. I mean, I have written functions for each eventlisteners . Do I need to remove eventlistener when control goes to the function definition.

I have written sample code

```
  var more:Image = new Image();
    more.width = 70;
    more.height=29;
    more.x=10;
    more.y=276;
    more.source = "Assets/more button.png";
    more.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MORE_clickHandler);
    mainGroup.addElement(more);



private function MORE_clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {

// Do I need to remove the eventlistener here

}
```

Also , do I need to explicitly nullify the object of Image class which I created or garbage collector will handle it.  If I need to explicitly nullify it, where to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection is an important part of any language, especially on mobile.  Since mobile devices are a lot more limited than say our desktop counterparts, you need to be very careful what is being created/stored to memory.  My motto is, if you don't see it, you shouldn't keep it.  You can destroy views but keep their state using a view model.

To remove a view, you need to first remove it from the display list (`removeElement(yourObject)`), remove all event listeners, and nullify any referencing variable.  If any variable still has a reference to it, it won't get garbage collected.

I recommend you read up a bit more on garbage collection as well as some neat tricks like pooling and virtualization (item renderers in a list).

Comment: Hi J_A_X, How and where to remove event listeners and where to nullify referencing  variable. Can u please show me an example

Comment: I can't show an example because it depends on the behavior you're trying to accomplish.  it's as simple as calling `removeEventListener`, removing from the display list with `removeElement` and do `yourVar = null;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an event listerener with a weak reference.

This implies that when the only reference to your object is the listener, the object itself can still be garbage collected and the listener will not keep it in memory.

The following will do the trick :

```
more.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MORE_clickHandler,false, 0, true);
```

Another option would be to subclass the image class and let it implement an `IDisposable` interface, which would force you to implement a `dispose()` method.

Some handy resources:
http://www.intriguemedia.net/2007/09/24/when-to-use-weak-references
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html

cheers

Comment: Using weak references is frowned upon because 1) it encourages sloppy coding and 2) mark & sweep garbage collecting is slower than reference counting (ie. when you clean up your own event listeners)